# Fix height of android EditText with a background

Tags: android

How can I get the button and the editText to have the same height? I want the EditText to have the height of the button View

```
<com.devmarvel.creditcardentry.library.CreditCardForm
    android:id="@+id/credit_card_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dip_40"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dip_20"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dip_20"
    app:text_color="@color/textColor"
    app:hint_text_color="@color/hintColor"
    app:cursor_color="@color/hintColor"
    app:include_helper="true"
    app:include_zip="false"
    app:input_background="@drawable/back_gray_border_round"
    app:include_exp="true"
    app:include_security="true"
    app:card_number_hint="@string/cardhint" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dip_10"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dip_20"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dip_20"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_button"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font_size"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I am using a library defined editText, but it does not have any height attribute.

Comment: use same margin for `button` and your `edittext` as i can see top margin for edittext is 40 whereas button's top margin is 10 only.

Comment: Set a fixed height for both elements or wrap them in a linearlayout with a fixed height and the elements can have match_parent as height.

Comment: I tried the linear_layout idea, but it didnt help

Answer (score 1):

Add Both EditText and Button in RelativeLayout and use alginTop and alignBottom property on EditText.Have a look on code.I have hard code button size for illustration purpose.

```
<RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="test"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:text="test2"/>
```

Comment: How does it help to fix them to have same heights?

Comment: By adding alignBottom and alignTop,Edittext will try to match botttom and top with button.So height would be same.